# Targetting the distribution of distances between points

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

For a certain problem, I need to make distance dependent statistics, but with the constraint that the number of sampling points, $N$, should be kept as small as possible. To be more specific I need to get a set of points in $\mathbb T^d$, ($\mathbb T=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is the one dimensional torus,
and $\mathbb T^d$ the $d$ dimensional torus)
$$S=\{x_1,\,x_2,\dots,\,x_N\}\subset\mathbb T^d$$
such that the distances
$$D=\{\|x-y\|, \text{such that}\; x,y\in S, x\neq y\}$$
are as evenly distributed as possible on $[0,\frac12\sqrt d]$.

I have started to create the set $S$ by picking random points uniformly.
Unfortunately, this is not satisfying because the distribution of distances $r$ is quite uneven (see the figure displaying the distribution of distances between two random points in $\mathbb T^3$). As a result, short and large distances are almost not sampled. I have then tried to use random walks to cure the short distance problem, but it is not very efficient and it is still bad for large distances.

[image: probability distribution of the distance $r$ between two random points in $\mathbb T^3$]

Is there a way to chose the elements of $S$ more efficiently ?

Comment: I think you need some further constraint on how you want the points to lie. Otherwise the obvious solution is just to sample them uniformly from a line, with perfectly uniform distance distribution.

Comment: @joriki. A line of $n$ points with distance $\delta$ between two successive ones will sample short distances much more than large ones, since there are $n-k$ pairs of points separated by $k\delta$.

Comment: I was thinking of an "infinite" line that wraps around the torus.